# Counted as halved/half?

Tags: phrase-choice

Does it sound better to use *counted halved*/ *counted as halved*/ or *counted half?* The context is below:

*The amount of time used on unpaid parental leave will be counted as halved towards his/ her total years of teaching*

or

*The amount of time used on unpaid parental leave will be counted as half towards his/ her total years of teaching*

Comment: The whole sentence is kind of awkward and confusing.  I would rephrase it something like "Time spent on unpaid paternal leave will count at 50% towards total years of teaching" or maybe "will count at half value".  (BTW, if it's "paternal leave", then it can only be **his** total years, because "paternal" means "having to do with a father".  Unless you meant "parental leave"?)

Comment: The ordinary way of saying this is that *Half of the amount of time ... will be counted toward ..."

Comment: I agree "Half the amount of time..." is a much clearly way to phrase the idea.

Comment: I cannot understand what you want to communicate. *To count something toward teaching years* does not make sense to me. Can you explain the entire idea, perhaps in several simple sentences?

Comment: @Jim Reynolds Sorry about that. It is like a pension point system for teachers working at public schools. The higher the credits or points will allow them to receive higher pensions. And since unpaid paternal leave can not be 100% counted as time of service, this rule will divide the time the teacher spent on parental leave by 2 and then add it to the total years of service. I hope I have clarified.

Comment: @stangdon Sorry for the mistake. It is parental leave. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per OP's comment at present, one wording choice might be:

> Fifty percent of time taken for unpaid parental leave shall accrue to total teaching years.

In response to the specific questions posed,

> Time used as X will be counted as halved towards Y . . .

And

> Time used as X will be counted as half towards Y . . .

. .  . are both unclear to me. I don't think the average reader could understand what you want to communicate from such language.

Answer (score 2):

It may be **simpler** and more **straightforward** to use **half**.

It may also be better to use **half** at **the beginning of the sentence** since it is the **allocation** of time which is **of interest**.

> **Half** of the piece of cake was given to Emma and the other **half** to William.

**Halved** is a verb to divide something into two, but requires a mental calculation

> The piece of cake was **halved** and given to  Emma and William.

Both sentences have exactly the same meaning, however the first may be more **straightforward**.

Your original sentence could be rewritten as

> **Half** of the used unpaid paternal leave time will be credited toward total years of teaching
>   Used unpaid paternal leave time will be **halved** and credited toward total years of teaching

assuming **paternal leave time** could be both **paid** and **unpaid** (otherwise **unpaid** is redundant)

Your original sentences sound a little convoluted.

Comment: FYI, I think the meaning of *to count X as halfway toward Y* is unclear in this context (or any other I can think of).